# How to run principal axis factor analysis (pa) with no iteration?

Tags: r

I am trying to run a principal axis factor analysis (pa) using the -fa- function from the -psych- package with no iteration. How can I go about doing this using the -fa- function?

I tried to solve this issue using the following code but I am getting the following messsage "maximum iteration exceeded".

```
fmodel3 <- fa(trening3_comp,
          fm="pa", 
          nfactors = 2,
          rotate = "none", 
          max.iter = 0
          )
```

Comment: Please, see it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: maybe you prefer to use the `principal` function which does PCA and FA by eigen-decomposition, an analytic solution rather than the iterative one (maximum likelihood estimation)